# Series capacitor voltage divider in DC logic

Tags: capacitor

Why capacitor connected in series acts a voltage divider in DC? In DC capacitor is OPEN circuit, no current can path through it. Voltage divider assumes we need to have current run through it. How is it possible?

UPDATED photo:
[image]

Comment: Show us the circuit you are talking about.

Comment: @lub2354 can you draw a circuit? edit the question and use the circuit tool

Comment: Hello ,I have updated the post with the photo. it charged the capacitor to some DC value and between them half of the voltage charged. Why is that.

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem, it's not a DC circuit.

That's a half bridge converter.

It alternatively connects the primary to supply voltage or ground. So there is no DC current but only AC current through the capacitors.

So the capacitors are open circuits at DC and there are likely DC bias/balancing resistors to set the DC operating point. But for AC capacitors are low impedance or short circuits.

Even if there would be no resistors, charging two identical capacitors that are in series with some current will charge both capacitors with equal voltage, so there would be half voltage point in the middle of the capacitors. The bias resistors just handle the difference in capacitor tolerance and leakage currents.

Comment: Hello Justme, I actually saw how he charges the capacitors ,
and then with a voltmeter masures DC voltage half the value he charged them.
minute 24:00
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCQhGE176Bg&t=215s

Comment: I don't see what is the use of that link.

Comment: Hello Justme,he charges the capacitors , and then with a voltmeter masures DC voltage half the value he charged them.how its possible

Comment: I already explained that charging two capacitors in series to voltage X means  each capacitors have half the voltage of X over them because they add up in series to full voltage X.

Comment: Q=C*V ->C1=2C C2=2C, Q=2C*(V/2)  why  in series connection we store the same amount of charge on each capacitor? thanks.

Comment: Because capacitors are identical. Why would there be different charge or voltage? Another example, you have 10V over two 10k resistors in series, so there is 5V over each resistor and identical current flows through both.

Answer (score 1):

Real world capacitor can be model as an ideal capacitor and resistor in parallel. The equivalent resistance can be really high, like 100Meg ohm or even higher, depending on the capacitor quality.  Therefore, they can form a voltage divider network.

However, the half Vcc point cannot drive DC load, like a resistor. Any resistor, even a 1Meg ohm resistor, between the half Vcc point and GND will easily pull down the voltage.

Comment: Hello ,I have updated the post with the photo.
it charged the capacitor to some DC value and between them half of the voltage charged.
Why is that.